# Assigning a series to a multi-index column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider the following:

```
import itertools

index_levels = [['foo', 'bar'], ['something', 'something_else']]
midx         = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(index_levels, names=['one', 'two']
df           = pd.DataFrame(columns=midx)
```

The following works:

```
df['foo', 'something']] = pd.Series(np.random.randn(20,))
```

but the following doesn't:

```
df.loc[:, idx['foo', 'something']] = pd.Series(np.random.randn(20,))
```

we get the following error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Why?

Note that this type of Series-to-column assignment works without problem when the column depth is 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['foo'])
df.loc[:, 'foo'] = pd.Series(np.random.randn(20,))
```

The following also works: